# Android OneBusAway - How do I change colors?

Tags: java, android

I'm not an android develop at all but I've been tasked with updating colors and styles for [OneBusAway](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway/wiki).  Nothing fancy is required.  Examples are changing the header area for green to purple or something like make the default grey background color a darker grey color. I figure that I should be able to open the code, change some hex colors, build and be done.

This should all be really simple but I cannot find where the actual colors get set.

For example, take a look at the code below:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/stop_info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_busbot"
            android:visibility="gone">
```

I want to change the background color.  So, I search for ab_stacked_solid_busbot which leads me to the following:

```
public static final int ab_stacked_solid_busbot=0x7f020002;
```

This does not at all look like a style to me. However, it could potentially be a hex or RBA value but can't get it to match the existing app colors.

In styles.xml, I can find the following:

```
<style name="HeaderItem">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_busbot</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
</style>
```

This still seems like there is a pointer to a style class somewhere with an atual color attached to it.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I can make these simple color changes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that line you found is from the generated `R.java` file. That is an internal id used by the OS to find the drawable image. Take a look in your drawable folders and you should find an image or xml named `ab_stacked_solid_busbot`. You will need to modify the xml or in your image editor of choice based on the type.

Comment: it may not be an actual image it could be xml drawable... but yes dcharm has it right

Comment: I updated my question with some xml from Styles.xml. Does this indicate that the background is using drawable sml?

Comment: What is in your drawable folders? That is what you need to zero in on and modify.

Comment: There isn't much in the drawable folder.  A handful of images and maybe 10 or 12 xml files.  None of them seems to correspond to what I'm looking for.  Wouldn't a global search but enough to look everywhere?   Am I really just looking for an image?

Comment: There is a file somewhere in one of your drawable folders with the name `ab_stacked_solid_busbot`. It can either be an xml or .png. Make sure you look in all of the `drawable-xxx` folders.

Comment: I looked inside the drawable-mdp folder and it looks like my answers may be found in there.  Stay tuned....

Answer (score 0):

hex color bro.... here

http://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/

find the color you want here.... and it will tell you the hex(six digit code)
you can set the background directly to the color like so...

```
android:background="#000000"
```

if your knoow the hex or rgb of the color you want u can use the above site to convert from one to the other, otherwise play with it til the color matches and youll have your code

Comment: I can't do it that way.  I need to change the global styles. change once, works everywhere.Do you know how I can change the styles for ab_stacked_solid_busbot?

Comment: 0x7f020002 is the image id... did u pull that from r.java? check your drawables folder and see if you find ab_stacked_solid_busbot in there.... either  in xml, or png. then replace that

Comment: There isn't an image of that name in the drawable folder.  The app is riddled with similar items.

Comment: show me the class that says   public static final int ab_stacked_solid_busbot=0x7f020002;